# Oracle select max id from table returns null value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, max

I have the query:

```
SELECT MAX(prod_id) FROM products;
```

It returns the maximum value if there are records. But, if I truncate table and run the same query I am unable to get the `max` id.

Comment: is there any way to get max id if i truncate table

Comment: if you remove all data in the table then there is **absolutely no way to get any data out of the table**. So, no. See both answers below. I've put a link to the `truncate` documentation in my answer so you can read it if you need more information on what `truncate` does to your table.

Answer (score 22):

In case you want to query a table's column and suspect that the max function may return null, then you can return 0 in case null is encountered

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(P.PROD_ID), 0) AS MAX_VAL
 FROM PRODUCTS P
```

This will return at least 0 , if no value is encountered for the column that you mention ()

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by [truncating](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10006.htm) the table you have removed all data in it, with no need for a `commit`. Therefore there is no data in the table and the `max` of nothing is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you truncate the table, there are no rows left in the table.  By definition, Max() returns NULL when run against an empty table.... or did I miss something here?

Comment: I was thinking... In Oracle, if prod_id is a defined with a sequence, then

SELECT prod_id.currval FROM DUAL

will get you the last used number, which may also be the max depending upon how the sequence was defined.

Answer (score 0):

As Gerald P. Wright commented to an answer, if id is generated by a sequence, you can use it to find the value.
But

```
SELECT prod_id_seq.currval FROM DUAL
```

won't work, because currval works only in the session where you fetched a value with currval.

so,

```
SELECT prod_id_seq.nextval FROM DUAL
```

can be an workaround for you, but would be a realy, realy BAD solution(if you get the id with this several times you'll get incremented values).

Comment: If also depends on the cache of the sequence.